# Mup deploy failing on linux

Tags: meteor, deployment, meteor-up

I am using `mup version 0.11.2` for quite a while, and never had any problems with updating my meteor app previously.

But now I am getting an error when I am trying to upload a new version of my app. I am getting the following error -

```
mup deploy
```

Meteor Up: Production Quality Meteor Deployments

Building Started: .

```
=> Build Error. Check the logs printed above.
```

But when I check the log using mup logs -f it says

```
tail: cannot open /var/log/upstart/allsaid.log for reading[server ip] : No such file or directory
```

So I am not seeing the actual error which causes the deployment fail.

Here is the OS and version I am having on machine using for deploy

```
uname -a
Linux x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Node - 0.10.38
NPM - 1.4.28
Meteor - 1.1.0.3
```

I have tried mupx too but it is also getting stuck on mup setup command.

```
mupx logs -f shows "docker command not found"
```

Can anyone help me out to fix this issue?